# How do i display the EA name in the following sentence?

Tags: mql4

I have an EA, anytime it execute a trade when i hover my mouse on the trade in the Trade tab it displays the following sentences "Buy order, placed by expert, Expert id 101". I have tried using `WindowExpertName();` to set the name but am not getting it. What i want is, i want it to display the name of the EA like the following "Buy order, placed by expert, PipsTaker id 101".

Answer (score 1):

The [`OrderSend()`](https://docs.mql4.com/en/trading/ordersend) function has a `comment` among its fields, right before the `magic`.

Use `WindowExpertName()` when passing data into the `comment`

Comment: Thank you for your response